# Retrieving value of checkbox in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I want to retrieve the value of my checkbox when it is checked.

I am using this "http://react-component.github.io/checkbox/".

My code looks like this.

```
<div className="user_box">
    { check.map((values , i)=> {
        return <Checkbox
            name = "checkbox"
            onChange={this.checkvalue.bind(this)}
            value={values.username} 
        />
    })}
</div>
```

My function:

```
checkvalue(e){
    // var all_users = [];
    // var value = this.checkbox.value;
    // all_users.push(value);
    // console.log(all_users);

    console.log('checkbox checked:', (e.target.checked));
}
```

I'm not understanding how to retrieve the value of the checkbox.

Comment: Hey, can you make a jsfiddle/code snippet so we can help you ? :)

Comment: its difficult to explain on jsfiddle because. i cant explain, what output i want

Comment: Using the default `e.target.value` just getting the value `on` every time

Answer (score 54, accepted):

you need to pass the "e, Synthetic event parameter to your handler" :

```
handleChange(e) {
  let isChecked = e.target.checked;
  // do whatever you want with isChecked value
}

render() {
  // ... your code here
  return (
    {/* your other jsx here */}
    <Checkbox otherProps onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} />
    {/* your other jsx here */}
  );
}
```

Comment: the same thing works when we change the `onChange` attribute with `onChange={this.handleChange}`, can you please explain why? How do they differ?

Comment: @PrameshBajracharya Because using {this.handleChange} passes a function, and onChange expects a function. I/O is compatible and hence why it works.

Comment: How are you doing this? On mine, `e.target.checked` is **undefined**

Answer (score 9):

Use the Synthetic event parameter, here is an example:

```
const element1 = "boy";
const element2 = "girl";

<input
 type="checkbox"
 name={element1}
 value={element1}
 onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
<label for="element" style={{ fontSize: 35 }}>
{element2}
 </label>

<input
 type="checkbox"
 name={element2}
 value={element2}
 onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
<label for="element" style={{ fontSize: 35 }}>
{element2}
 </label>




handleChange = (e) => {
// to find out if it's checked or not; returns true or false
const checked = e.target.checked;

// to get the checked value
const checkedValue = e.target.value;

// to get the checked name
const checkedName = e.target.name;

//then you can do with the value all you want to do with it.
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
getChckeboxValue(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
}
```

In render:

```
<input onClick={this.getChckeboxValue.bind(this)} type="checkbox" value="Text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

```
onChange={e => doSomethingWithValue( e.currentTarget.checked )}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get check box value by declaring `onChange={this.likeClicked}  defaultChecked={false}` on input element properties

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.likeClicked = this.likeClicked.bind(this)
  }

  likeClicked(){
    console.log(event.target.checked, event.target.id);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className='px-3'>
          <div className='item-header item-wrapper cirle'>
            <input 
               type="checkbox" 
               onChange={this.likeClicked}  
               defaultChecked={false}  
               className="checkbox" 
               id={`checkbox_${this.props.product.sku}`} 
            />
            <label htmlFor={`checkbox_${this.props.product.sku}`}> 
               <HeartIcon className="heart-svg"></HeartIcon>
            </label>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to get the checkbox status value with the existing form data like input, select. here is the code

```
 const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    const formFieldValue = e.target.type === 'checkbox' ? e.target.checked : e.target.value
    setFormValues({
      [e.target.name]: formFieldValue,
    })
  }
```