# get value of checkbox in react js

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

How to get the value of checkbox in react js , it is always returning false (boolean value)
this is my snippet code

```
export default class CreateMateriel extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onChangeEtat = this.onChangeEtat.bind(this);


  this.state = {
        etat: false

onChangeEtat(e) {
    this.setState({
        etat: e.target.value
    });
```

the html code part

```
                    <input type="checkbox" className="form-control" value={this.state.etat}
                           onChange={!this.onChangeEtat}/>
```

Please do anyone has an idea?

Comment: `onChange={this.onChangeEtat}` and 

`onChangeEtat(e) {
    this.setState({
        etat: e.target.checked
    });`

Comment: Thanks @ShivamJha     onChangeEtat(e) {
        this.setState({
            etat: e.target.checked
        });
        console.log(e.target.checked)
    }

Comment: Put it in a reply so I make it the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can [acess whether checkbox is checkd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39267669/retrieving-value-of-checkbox-in-react-js/45784215) using `e.target.checked`:

```
onChangeEtat(e) {
    this.setState({
        etat: e.target.checked
    });
}
```